# semi continious functions characterizations

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Does anyone knows how to prove this:

Let $f: (X, d) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an upper semi-continious function.

Prove that $f$ is u.s.c. if and only if $ \{ x \ \ |\ \ f(x) \geq z \} $ is closed $\forall z \in \mathbb{R}$

Hope someone knows

Comment: Which definition of upper semicontinuity are you working with? In the natural definition, it is immediate.

Comment: I'm using:
$f:(X,d) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is u.s.c on $x_0$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \ \ \exists \delta > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq f(x_0) + \epsilon \ \ \forall x \in  B_{\epsilon}(x_0)$.

Comment: That must be $f(x) \leqslant f(x_0) + \epsilon$. Just a typo, I presume.

Comment: Take three properties, 1. $f$ is u.s.c. at all $x\in X$, 2. for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $f^{-1}([z,+\infty))$ is closed, 3. for all $z\in \mathbb{R}$ the set $f^{-1}((-\infty,z))$ is open. The equivalence of 2. and 3. is direct, and the equivalence of 1. and 3. is easier to show than the equivalence of 1. and 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $f:R^n\rightarrow R$ be a lower semi-continuity function, how to show for any constant $r$ , $U=\{z\in R^n : f(z)&gt; r\}$ is open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814567/let-frn-rightarrow-r-be-a-lower-semi-continuity-function-how-to-show-for-an)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_z := \{x \, |\, f(x) \ge z\}$, for all $z \in \Bbb R$. Suppose $A_z$ is closed for every $z$. Then given $x_0 \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, the set $U_{x_0,\epsilon} := X \setminus A_{f(x_0) + \epsilon}$ is an open neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $f(x) < f(x_0) + \epsilon$ for all $x \in U_{x_0,\epsilon}$. Hence $f$ is upper semi-continuous.

Conversely, suppose $f$ is upper semi-continuous. Fix $z\in \Bbb R$. Given $x_0 \in X \setminus A_z$, set $\epsilon = z - f(x_0)$. Then $\epsilon > 0$. So by upper semi-continuity of $f$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $f(x) < f(x_0) + \epsilon = z$ for all $x\in U$. Hence $x_0 \in U \subset X \setminus A_z$. It follows that $X \setminus A_z$ is open, so $A_z$ is closed.